# Ordering windows in vim

Tags: vim

I'm now dealing with many windows in a single vim tab and sometimes fill anxious trying to rearrange them.

E.g. I have the following scheme:

```
+-------------------------+
+      +        +         +
+  A   +   B    +    C    +
+      +        +         +   
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+          D              +   
+                         +   
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+          E              +   
+                         +   
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

And want to get this without reopening all my windows but just doing some commands over D and E windows.

```
+-------------------------+
+      +        +         +   
+  A   +   B    +    C    +   
+      +        +         +   
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+          +              +   
+          +              +   
+    D     +       E      +   
+          +              +   
+          +              +   
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

I cannot think over doing this using shortcuts I found in helpfile (Ctrl-W + HJKL and so on). Is it possible to do complex window arrangement using standard vim? Or maybe there is a plugin which can help doing it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- focus `D` then `:hide`
- when focus on `E`, `:vs D` (D here is file name) If you want to play with buffer number, you can `:vert sbx` (`x` here is buffer number of `D`) or `:vert sb#` to use alternative buffer.

If you have set `splitright` like me, exchange the `D` and `E` above.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about :hide. Worked for me. 
Probably you meant :vs D in the second line.

Comment: @IvanSmirnov yes, it should be `D`, `E` makes no sense. :)

Comment: `<c-w>v<c-6>`  might be easier than `:vert sb#` for some people